# How to port Wix 3.0 project (with bootstrapper) to Wix 3.7

Tags: wix, upgrade, wix3, wix3.7

i've inherited a setup project which uses Wix 3.0
For programming reason we must switch to VS2012 and therefore to Wix 3.7, too.

While reading about Wix 3.7 i found out that 3.7 offers project type "Setup project"
and project type "Bootstrapper project".

My first question is: Have i to make a Setup project as before AND a bootstrapper project and combine it or just a bootstrapper project.

Using Wix 3.0 the bootstrapper stuff was located in the wixproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
    <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
  </BootstrapperFile>
  <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
    <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
  </BootstrapperFile>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <GenerateBootstrapper Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' " ApplicationName="$(ProductName)" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="True" OutputPath="$(TargetDir)%(CultureGroup.OutputFolder)" Culture="%(CultureGroup.Identity)" FallbackCulture="en-us" Path="$(WindowsSDKPath)" />
  <GenerateBootstrapper Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' " ApplicationName="$(ProductName) (x64)" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="HomeSite" CopyComponents="True" OutputPath="$(TargetDir)%(CultureGroup.OutputFolder)" Culture="%(CultureGroup.Identity)" FallbackCulture="en-us" Path="$(WindowsSDKPath)" />
</Target>
```

Is this still possible? Here i have to change from .Net 3.5SP1 to .Net 4.5

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you could upgrade by just using WiX Toolset 3.7 and running wixcop on your WiX files to upgrade them.

---

If you want to use the new WiX bootstrapper...

You need both project types. A "Setup" project creates an .msi file. A "Bootstrapper" project creates an .exe file.

Remove the Visual Studio Bootstrapper items and GenerateBootstrapper tasks from your setup project. Create corresponding ExePackage or PackageGroupRef elements in your bootstrapper's Chain. A PackageGroup roughly corresponds to a Visual Studio Bootstrapper package but the "syntax" is different. To recreate a Visual Studio Bootstrapper package consult the files under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bootstrapper\Packages` or equivalent.

For the Microsoft .NET framework, the WixNetfxExtension extension defines package groups that you can just [reference](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm).